# Flush cache to DRAM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, xilinx, zynq

I'm using a Xilinx Zynq platform with a region of memory shared between the programmable HW and the ARM processor.

I've reserved this memory using memmap on the kernel command line and then exposed it to userspace via mmap/io_remap_pfn_range calls in my driver.

The problem I'm having is that it takes some time for the writes to show up in DRAM and I presume it's stuck in dcache.  There's a bunch of flush_cache_* calls defined but none of them are exported, which is a clue to me that I'm barking up the wrong tree...

As a trial I locally exported flush_cache_mm and just to see what would happen and no joy.

In short, how can I be sure that any writes to this mmap'd regions have been committed to DRAM?

Thanks.

Comment: [memory.txt](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/Documentation/arm/memory.txt) shows the types of memory available from Linux kernel space.  These memory options might serve you better than the *memmap* command line.  You can handle command line arguments in a driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush the CPU cache for a region of address space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701352/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-for-a-region-of-address-space-in-linux)

Answer (score 10):

The **ARM** processors typically have both a *I/D cache* and a *write buffer*.  The idea of a *write buffer* is to gang sequential writes together (great for *synchronous DRAM*) and to not delay the CPU to wait for a *write* to complete.

To be *generic*, you can flush the *d cache* and the *write buffer*.  The following is some inline **ARM** assembler which should work for many *architectures* and memory configurations.

```
 static inline void dcache_clean(void)
 {
     const int zero = 0;
     /* clean entire D cache -> push to external memory. */
     __asm volatile ("1: mrc p15, 0, r15, c7, c10, 3\n"
                     " bne 1b\n" ::: "cc");
     /* drain the write buffer */
    __asm volatile ("mcr 15, 0, %0, c7, c10, 4"::"r" (zero));
 }
```

You may need more if you have an *L2 cache*.

To answer in a Linux context, there are different **CPU** variants and different routines depending on memory/MMU configurations and even CPU errata.  See for instance,

- [proc-arm926.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/proc-arm926.S)
- [cache-v7.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/cache-v7.S)
- [cache-v6.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/cache-v6.S)
- *etc*

These routines are either called directly or looked up in a *cpu info* structure with function pointers to the appropriate routine for the detected CPU and configuration; depending on whether the kernel is *special purpose for a single CPU* or *multi-purpose* like a **Ubuntu distribution**.

To answer the question specifically for your situation, we need to know *L2 cache*, *write buffered* memory, *CPU architecture* specifics; maybe including silicon revisions for *errata*.  Another tactic is to avoid this completely by using the [`dma_alloc_XXX()`  routines](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/dma-mapping.h) which mark memory as *un-cacheable* and *un-bufferable* so that the CPU writes are pushed externally immediately.  Depending on your memory access pattern, either solution is valid.  You may wish to cache if the memory only needs to be *synchronized* at some checkpoint (*vsync*/*hsync* for video, etc).

Comment: Clean entire D-cache does not work on ARMv7 (and I think the Zynq is a Cortex-A9). Also, it is a privileged operation, so would undef from userspace.

Comment: [cache-v7.S](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/arch/arm/mm/cache-v7.S) for the *github* Xilinx tree might be more appropriate; although cursorily, it looks the same as the mainline.  My intent was to be more generic and hope that the OP would understand something instead of spoon feeding.  Mainly, it is almost always better not to use *cacheable* or *bufferable* memory in these cases.

Comment: @unixsmurf All of those routines are meant to run in *supervisor* mode. I just meant to show the two steps; `v7_flush_dcache_all()` in **cache-v7.S** might be more appropriate for a Cortex-A9.  The *driver* would have to provide a mechanism to *flush* from *user space*, like an `ioctl()` command, or `proc` or `sysfs` file entries.  Thanks, I thought this was obvious and it probably isn't.

Comment: Yes, I've already implemented the 'flush' function as a ioctl in my driver.  Thus far I've not seen any improvement in behavior.  Lots of good info in here though.  Right now I've been attempting to use flush_cache_all().  I see v7_flush_dcache_all declared in cache-v7.S but it's not clear to me how to call this asm function from my driver...

Answer (score 4):

I hit the exact same problem, on zynq. Finally got L2 flushed/invalidated with:

```
#include <asm/outercache.h>
outer_cache.flush_range(start,size);
outer_cache.inv_range(start,size);
```

start is a kernel virtual space pointer. You also need to flush L1 to L2:

```
__cpuc_flush_dcache_area(start,size);
```

I'm not sure if invalidating L1 is needed before reading, and I haven't found the function to do this. I assume it would need to be, and I've thus far only been lucky...

Seems any suggestions on the 'net that I found assume the device to be "inside" of the L2 cache coherency, so they did not work if the AXI-HP ports were used. With the AXI-ACP port used, L2 flushing was not needed.
(For those not familiar with zync: the HP-ports access the DRAM controller directly, bypassing any cache/MMU implemented on ARM side)

Comment: [ACE versus AXI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470952/how-is-amba-ace-different-from-the-axi-protocol) is exactly the same sort of paradigm as AXI-HP (normal AXI) and AXI-ACP (ACE).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Zynq, but you essentially have two options that really work:

- either include your other logic on the FPGA in the same coherency domain (if Zynq has an ACP port, for example)
- or mark the memory you map as device memory (or other non-cacheable if you don't care about gather, reorder and early write acknowledge) and use a DSB after any write that should be seen.

If the memory is marked as cacheable and your other observer is not in the same coherency domain you are asking for trouble - when you clean the D-cache with a DCCISW or similar op and you have an L2 cache - that's where it'll all end up in.