# Writing to HW registers via /dev/mem needs extra write

Tags: arm, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, memory-barriers

Writing to HW registers via /dev/mem needs extra write

I want to write to some HW registers using /dev/mem on Linux.
The target board is ZYBO (Zynq, ARM Cortex-A9), and the HW is AXI4 Lite Slave with 4 registers which is automatically generated by Xilinx Vivado.

Here is the C code to write to the HW registers.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAP_BASE        (0x43c30000)
#define MAP_RANGE       (0x10000)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        volatile unsigned int *p;
        void *iomap_ptr;
        int fd, i, v;

        fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
        iomap_ptr = mmap(0, MAP_RANGE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, MAP_BASE);

        p = (volatile unsigned int *)iomap_ptr;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                p[i] = i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                printf("%04X: %08X\n", i, p[i]);

        munmap(iomap_ptr, MAP_RANGE);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

When I run the C code first time, the result is:

```
0000: 00000000
0001: 00000001
0002: 00000002
0003: 00000000
```

It seems that the final write is not applied.

Then, when I run the C code once again, the result is:

```
0000: 00000000
0001: 00000001
0002: 00000002
0003: 00000003
```

After investigation, I realized that I need an extra write to the HW in order to apply the last write.

How can I write to the HW registers without an extra write?

Comment: Do you need to flush part of the D-Cache? Xilinx should have some macros/functions for invalidating/flushing the cache for specific address ranges.

Comment: @rjp: It that address space is not "non-sharable/non-cachabe/strictly ordered" (hope I didn't miss something), the hardware-design is broken. Cache-problems should not arise on peripheral register space.

Comment: @Olaf, I don't disagree. I haven't worked on the Vivado side, so I don't know if that's something that needs to be specified and/or if it is something that can be setup incorrectly.

Comment: Sidenote: don't use standard integer types for peripheral registers and where else you need fixed width types. Use `stdint.h` types. Also it is good practice to encapsulate the full register pointer definition into the macro. This avoids manual casting each time you use that pointer which is error-prone.

Comment: I removed Video DMAs, Protocol Converter, and Interconnects from the Digilent's base system degisn. Then finally, the C code worked properly somehow. It's strange... I think the base system design or my design acted as a FIFO. Anyway, thank you all for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preface this, I somehow missed important information in the question, so the content of this answer is far less portable than it needs to be, but I believe it may still solve the problem. There are two related questions on SO specific to the Zynq and mmap:

[Flush cache to DRAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896812/flush-cache-to-dram)

[How to get writes via an mmap mapped memory pointer to flush immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750176/how-to-get-writes-via-an-mmap-mapped-memory-pointer-to-flush-immediately)

The Xilinx cache functions listed here appear to ultimately use the same method as the top answer in the first linked question.

---

This is likely a caching issue. In this specific case, you can use the Xilinx library to flush the address range that your registers are in. The header file `xil_cache.h` has two functions that can be used for this:

```
void Xil_DCacheFlush(void); 
void Xil_DCacheFlushRange(unsigned int adr, unsigned len);
```

Depending on version, you may have a third option (with slightly different prototypes):

```
void Xil_DCacheFlush(void);
void Xil_DCacheFlushRange(INTPTR adr, u32 len);
void Xil_DCacheFlushLine(INTPTR adr);
```

The first function, `Xil_DCacheFlush` will flush the entire cache. This isn't a particularly desirable behavior, as there will potentially be a lot of cached data that isn't relevant to the issue getting flushed and invalidated, so you may see a performance impact.

The third function, `Xil_DCacheFlushLine` if available, will likely work in this case, since you only have four registers. It will force the writes (if the line is dirty) and then invalidate the cache so the next read will be a miss and have to fetch from your register. This isn't the best solution, though, as it relies on a few assumptions about your peripheral.

The second function, `Xil_DCacheFlushRange` is probably the function you want. Using this function, you can specify the range of addresses of your peripheral. In this case, it is small, but this solution is scalable for complicated peripherals with very large register sets.

After you perform your register writes to the peripheral, you should be able to call whichever of the above functions you prefer to flush all or part of the data cache.

There may also be a way to disable caching of this address range in your design, though I am having difficulty locating a good reference for this, and you may not have the granularity in region location/size that you desire.

Comment: If /dev/mem gives back a cacheable mapping, something's probably gone horribly wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed that bit. It does look like other people have had the same problem on the Zynq: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750176/how-to-get-writes-via-an-mmap-mapped-memory-pointer-to-flush-immediately

Comment: The more I think about this, the less it makes sense. The other questions do indeed relate to cache issues with `mmap` on the Zynq, but in this case, I don't see why the written value wouldn't come back, even if it didn't hit the peripheral registers, since the correct value should be in the cache.

Comment: I don't think the question can be answered. We don't know how the specific design is, nor about the specific kernel, etc.

Comment: Of course, if it's a non-cacheable, rather than device, mapping, then it could still be write-bufferable, but then the subsequent read should hit in the write buffer. Essentially, as far as the CPU, caches and interconnect are concerned (i.e. ,the architectural memory model) a write to an address followed by a read of the _same_ address, on the same CPU, should always return the value of the write, so it's most likely some timing issue with the peripheral itself. The best you can do from software is issue a DSB to force outstanding writes to complete.