# How is AMBA ACE different from the AXI protocol?

Tags: arm, amba

What is the difference between ADVANCED MICROCONTROLER BUS ARCHITECTURE-ACE and  ADVANCED MICROCONTROLER BUS ARCHITECTURE-AXI protocol?

Comment: What part of the documentation do you not understand?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is stated in the [ARM document](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0022/e/ACE-Protocol-Specification/About-ACE/Protocol-overview/About-the-ACE-protocol),

> The ACE protocol extends the AXI4 protocol and provides support for hardware-coherent caches.
>  ... 
> A five state cache model to define the state of any cache line in the coherent system.

See [MOESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol) at Wikipedia (five state cahce protocol).  It seems pretty clear,

The [AXI is a bus protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_eXtensible_Interface) which provides a means to transfer burst data from masters to slaves over a wide data path.  The **ACE** protocol extends the signalling to allow a MOESI type protocol to be used for cache coherency.

So, if you were to develop IP for a GPU (Vivante) and wanted to support cache coherency with a CPU, you would need the signals provide by ACE.  Otherwise, I think it is mainly between the CPU complex (4/8 etc cores) on the chip.   Also there is a trend to asymmetric multiple CPUs, so a legacy chip could talks to an ARM CPU.  Or you could have an ARM-to-RISCV translation.  It might also be useful to a machine learning type acceleration engine.

Most DMA masters do not perform work **WITH** a CPU.  So even a crypto engine probably would not need the ACE protocol signals.  Also, you could have a simple AXI connections between the devices in the paragraph above and it could work, but would be less performant.

Summarizing all that,

The AXI protocols are 'master' to 'slave' (provider/consumer, etc) where as the ACE is a master to master interface.  So AXI is useful for an Ethernet, Video, memory controller, but ACE will be used to co-ordinate computations between masters that process data in complex ways.  The ACE is a protocol to say that another *consumer* is working on that portion/section of the *provider* data and you should block or do something else.

Comment: A [good point in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896812/flush-cache-to-dram/25811344#25811344), ACP/ACE can be used to make a driver cache aware, which allows the CPU to map the device buffers with cache on.  There are a lot of devices where this doesn't give any advantage, and the extra gates to implement ACE are probably quite significant (cost, power, functionality sacrificed elsewhere).